# How do I batch this google app script better or at all?

Tags: javascript, performance, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spread sheet where people can enter values in column V and then click a button, the values they entered are taken and put into a row on another sheet in the same workbook.

The script I am using is slowing down significantly and I was wondering if I can make an changes to it to make it faster

Below is the script:

````
//function to validate the entry made by user in live wave tabs
function validateGnteEntry(){
  //declare a variable and set the reference of active google sheet
  var myGoogleSheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var shUserForm= myGoogleSheet.getSheetByName("GNTE Requester");

  var ui=SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); // create submit pop up 

  shUserForm.getRange("V3").setBackground('#EDE3FF'); //Indication
  shUserForm.getRange("V4").setBackground('#EDE3FF'); //BP Name
  shUserForm.getRange("V5").setBackground('#EDE3FF'); //Budget
  shUserForm.getRange("V6").setBackground('#EDE3FF'); //Wave Type
  shUserForm.getRange("V7").setBackground('#EDE3FF'); //Waves Sold
  shUserForm.getRange("V8").setBackground('#EDE3FF'); //GNTE Name
  shUserForm.getRange("V9").setBackground('#EDE3FF'); //Start
  shUserForm.getRange("V10").setBackground('#EDE3FFF'); //End
  shUserForm.getRange("V11").setBackground('#EDE3FF'); //Flight
  shUserForm.getRange("V12").setBackground('#EDE3FF'); //Total Targets
  shUserForm.getRange("V13").setBackground('#EDE3FF'); //GNTE Eng
  shUserForm.getRange("V14").setBackground('#EDE3FF'); //Desired Eng Rate (Not Required)
  shUserForm.getRange("V15").setBackground('#EDE3FF'); //CPE
  shUserForm.getRange("V16").setBackground('#EDE3FF'); //Notes
  shUserForm.getRange("V17").setBackground('#EDE3FF'); //Duration
  shUserForm.getRange("V18").setBackground('#EDE3FF'); //Parent GNTE
  shUserForm.getRange("V19").setBackground('#EDE3FF'); //Auidence ID
  shUserForm.getRange("V20").setBackground('#EDE3FF'); //CSM
  shUserForm.getRange("V21").setBackground('#EDE3FF'); //RVP
  shUserForm.getRange("V22").setBackground('#EDE3FF'); //CSM Slack ID
  shUserForm.getRange("V23").setBackground('#EDE3FF'); //RVP Slack ID
  shUserForm.getRange("V24").setBackground('#FFFF00'); //Upper and Lower
//Validation of GNTE ID
if(shUserForm.getRange('V18').isBlank()==true){
    ui.alert("Alert: Please enter a valid parent GNTE into cell V18");
    shUserForm.getRange('V18').activate();
    shUserForm.getRange("V18").setBackground('#FFFF00');
    return false;
}

return true;
}

//Function to submit the data to the database sheet

function createGnte(){

  //declare a variable and set the reference of active google sheet
  var myGoogleSheet= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var shUserForm= myGoogleSheet.getSheetByName("GNTE Requester");
  var datasheet= myGoogleSheet.getSheetByName("GNTE Request Database");

  //to create the instance of the user interface alert 

  var ui=SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var response=ui.alert("Submit", "Do you want to submit the data?", ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

  //checking the user repsone 

  if(response==ui.Button.NO){
    return; //to exit from this function
  }

  if(validateGnteEntry()==true){
    //id next blank row
    var blankRow=datasheet.getLastRow()+1; 

    //code to transfer the data
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow,1).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("V3").getValue()); //Indication
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow,2).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("V4").getValue()); //BP Name
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow,3).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("V5").getValue()); //Budget
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow,4).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("V6").getValue()); //Wave Type
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow,5).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("V7").getValue()); //Waves Sold
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow,6).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("V8").getValue()); //GNTE Name
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow,7).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("V9").getValue()); //Start
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow,8).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("V10").getValue()); //End
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow,10).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("V11").getValue()); //Flight
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow,11).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("V12").getValue()); //Total Targets
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow,12).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("V13").getValue()); //GNTE Eng
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow,25).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("V14").getValue()); //Desired Eng Rate (Not Required)
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow,13).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("V15").getValue()); //CPE
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow,14).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("V16").getValue()); //Notes
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow,9).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("V17").getValue()); //Duration
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow,15).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('mm/dd/YYY'); //time of submission
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow,16).setValue(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()); //submitted by
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow,17).setValue(""); //action required by
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow,18).setValue("Pending"); //Status
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow,23).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("V18").getValue()); //Link to Parent
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow,24).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("V19").getValue()); //Audience ID
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow,19).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("V20").getValue()); //CSM
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow,20).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("V21").getValue()); //RVP
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow,21).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("V22").getValue()); //CSMID
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow,22).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("V23").getValue()); //RVPID
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow,26).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("V24").getValue()); //Upper Lower


    shUserForm.getRange("V3").clear().setBackground('#EDE3FF');//indication
    shUserForm.getRange("V4").clear().setBackground('#EDE3FF');//BP Name
    shUserForm.getRange("V5").setFormula("=iferror(VLOOKUP(V3&V4,'Upper Lower Database'!A:P,MATCH(U5,'Upper Lower Database'!1:1,0),FALSE),)").setBackground('#EDE3FF');//Budget
    shUserForm.getRange("V6").setFormula("=iferror(VLOOKUP(V3&V4,'Upper Lower Database'!A:P,MATCH(U6,'Upper Lower Database'!1:1,0),FALSE),)").setBackground('#EDE3FF');//Wave Type
    shUserForm.getRange("V7").setFormula("=iferror(VLOOKUP(V3&V4,'Upper Lower Database'!A:P,MATCH(U7,'Upper Lower Database'!1:1,0),FALSE),)").setBackground('#EDE3FF');//Waves sold
    shUserForm.getRange("V8").clear().setBackground('#EDE3FF');//GNTE Name
    shUserForm.getRange("V9").setFormula("=iferror(VLOOKUP(V3&V4,'Upper Lower Database'!A:P,MATCH(U9,'Upper Lower Database'!1:1,0),FALSE),)").setBackground('#EDE3FF');//Start
    shUserForm.getRange("V10").clear().setBackground('#EDE3FF');//End
    shUserForm.getRange("V11").setFormula("=iferror(VLOOKUP(V3&V4,'Upper Lower Database'!A:P,MATCH(U11,'Upper Lower Database'!1:1,0),FALSE),)").setBackground('#EDE3FF');//Flight
    shUserForm.getRange("V12").clear().setBackground('#EDE3FF');
    shUserForm.getRange("V13").clear().setBackground('#EDE3FF');
    shUserForm.getRange("V14").setFormula("=IFERROR(V13/V12,0)").setBackground('#EDE3FF');//Desired eng rate
    shUserForm.getRange("V15").setFormula("=IFERROR(V5/V13,0)").setBackground('#EDE3FF');//Desired eng rate
    shUserForm.getRange("V16").clear().setBackground('#EDE3FF');
    shUserForm.getRange("V17").clear().setBackground('#EDE3FF');//Duration
    shUserForm.getRange("V18").clear().setBackground('#EDE3FF');//Parent GNTE
    shUserForm.getRange("V19").clear().setBackground('#EDE3FF');//Audience ID
    shUserForm.getRange("V20").setFormula("=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($V$3,'2023 Summary'!$C:$AQ,MATCH($U20,'2023 Summary'!$C$5:$AQ$5,0),false),)").setBackground('#EDE3FF');//CSM
    shUserForm.getRange("V21").setFormula("=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($V$3,'2023 Summary'!$C:$AQ,MATCH($U21,'2023 Summary'!$C$5:$AQ$5,0),false),)").setBackground('#EDE3FF');//RVP
    shUserForm.getRange("V22").setFormula("=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($V20,Vlookups!$I:$J,2,false),)").setBackground('#EDE3FF');//CSM Slack ID
    shUserForm.getRange("V23").setFormula("=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($V21,Vlookups!$I:$J,2,false),)").setBackground('#EDE3FF');//RVP Slack ID
    shUserForm.getRange("V24").clear().setBackground('#FFFF00');//upper and lower


  }
}```


im not sure what to try, im so new to this and trying to figure it out as I go
````

Comment: A [`Range`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range?hl=en) can describe a range of cells, so you do not need to access every cell individually. You can use the a1Notation e.g. `V1:V24` to get all the cells from `V1` to `V26` (one can also specify ranges using column indices). See the documentation on [`getRange()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet?hl=en#getrangea1notation). Thereby you can set the background color in one go e.g. `sheet.getRange("A1:A3").setBackground("#ffffff")`. You should also checkout JavaScript arrays.

Comment: Thank you @Mushroomator this definitely cuts down on lines 10 - 31 for sure

Comment: Line 17: `shUserForm.getRange("V10").setBackground('#EDE3FFF'); //End` There's an error here. The colour should be "#EDE3FF"

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of improving performance. I'm not suggesting that these scripts could not be made to run faster. but they should be noticeably quicker than the OP code.

**validateGnteEntry**

- 22 lines to set background reduced to two lines

`shUserForm.getRange("V3:V23").setBackground('#EDE3FF')`
`shUserForm.getRange("V24").setBackground('#FFFF00'); //Upper and Lower`

**createGnte**

- `var blankRow=datasheet.getLastRow()+1;` The blank row isn't required. It is replaced by [appendRow(rowContents)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendrowrowcontents)
- `datasheet.getRange(blankRow,1).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("V3").getValue())` - the 20-odd lines to `getValue` and `setValue` have been replaced by:

  - `var sourceData = shUserForm.getRange("V3:V24").getValues()` - this gets all the data in Column V
  - `var tempArray = [sourceData[0][0],sourceData[1][0],...` - the values from Column V are inserted into the array in the order required by the user.
  - `datasheet.appendRow(tempArray)` - `appendRow`: appends a row to the bottom of the current data region in the sheet. No need to find the last row.
- `shUserForm.getRange("V3:V23").clear().setBackground('#EDE3FF');` all but row 24 is cleared and the background is reset. The `setFormula` code has been kept, but the `setBackground` elements have been deleted.

---

```
function validateGnteEntry(){
  //declare a variable and set the reference of active google sheet
  var myGoogleSheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var shUserForm= myGoogleSheet.getSheetByName("GNTE Requester");

  shUserForm.getRange("V3:V23").setBackground('#EDE3FF')
  shUserForm.getRange("V24").setBackground('#FFFF00'); //Upper and Lower

  //Validation of GNTE ID
  if(shUserForm.getRange('V18').isBlank()==true){
    var ui=SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); // create submit pop up
    ui.alert("Alert: Please enter a valid parent GNTE into cell V18"); 

    shUserForm.getRange('V18').activate();
    shUserForm.getRange("V18").setBackground('#FFFF00');  
    return false;    
  }

return true;
}
```

---

```
//Function to submit the data to the database sheet

function createGnte(){
  //declare a variable and set the reference of active google sheet
  var myGoogleSheet= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var shUserForm= myGoogleSheet.getSheetByName("GNTE Requester");
  var datasheet= myGoogleSheet.getSheetByName("GNTE Request Database");

  //to create the instance of the user interface alert 

  var ui=SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var response=ui.alert("Submit", "Do you want to submit the data?", ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

  //checking the user repsone 

  if(response==ui.Button.NO){
    return; //to exit from this function
  }

  if(validateGnteEntry()==true){
    //id next blank row
    var blankRow=datasheet.getLastRow()+1; 
    // get the data in Column V
    var sourceData = shUserForm.getRange("V3:V24").getValues()
    // set a date
    var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "MM/dd/yyyy");
    // create a temproray array to hold the values
    var tempArray = []
    // assign the source data to the array
    //Row,1 = "V3" //Indication
    //Row,2 = "V4" //BP Name
    //Row,3 = "V5" //Budget
    //Row,4 = "V6" //Wave Type
    //Row,5 = "V7" //Waves Sold
    //Row,6 = "V8" //GNTE Name
    //Row,7 = "V9" //Start
    //Row,8 = "V10" //End
    //Row,9 = "V17" //Duration
    //Row,10 = "V11" //Flight
    //Row,11 = "V12" //Total Targets
    //Row,12 = "V13" //GNTE Eng
    //Row,13 = "V15" //CPE
    //Row,14 = "V16" //Notes
    //Row,15 = Totay's date 'mm/dd/YYY' //time of submission
    //Row,16 = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() //submitted by   
    //Row,17 = "" //action required by
    //Row,18 = "Pending" //Status
    //Row,19 = "V20" //CSM
    //Row,20 = "V21" //RVP
    //Row,21 = "V22" //CSMID
    //Row,22 = "V23" //RVPID
    //Row,23 = "V18" //Link to Parent
    //Row,24 = "V19" //Audience ID
    // Row,25 = "V14" //Desired Eng Rate (Not Required)
    // Row,26 = "V24" //Upper Lower

    // populate array
    var tempArray = [sourceData[0][0],sourceData[1][0],sourceData[2][0],sourceData[3][0],sourceData[4][0],sourceData[5][0],sourceData[6][0],sourceData[7][0],sourceData[14][0],sourceData[8][0],sourceData[9][0],sourceData[10][0],sourceData[12][0],sourceData[13][0],formattedDate,Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(),"","Pending",sourceData[17][0],sourceData[18][0],sourceData[19][0],sourceData[20][0],sourceData[15][0],sourceData[16][0],sourceData[11][0],sourceData[21][0]]

    // append array
    datasheet.appendRow(tempArray)
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: data copied")
    

    // clear and reset formats for form
    shUserForm.getRange("V3:V23").clear().setBackground('#EDE3FF');
    shUserForm.getRange("V5").setFormula("=iferror(VLOOKUP(V3&V4,'Upper Lower Database'!A:P,MATCH(U5,'Upper Lower Database'!1:1,0),FALSE),)") //Budget
    shUserForm.getRange("V6").setFormula("=iferror(VLOOKUP(V3&V4,'Upper Lower Database'!A:P,MATCH(U6,'Upper Lower Database'!1:1,0),FALSE),)") //Wave Type
    shUserForm.getRange("V7").setFormula("=iferror(VLOOKUP(V3&V4,'Upper Lower Database'!A:P,MATCH(U7,'Upper Lower Database'!1:1,0),FALSE),)") //Waves sold
    shUserForm.getRange("V9").setFormula("=iferror(VLOOKUP(V3&V4,'Upper Lower Database'!A:P,MATCH(U9,'Upper Lower Database'!1:1,0),FALSE),)") //Start
    shUserForm.getRange("V11").setFormula("=iferror(VLOOKUP(V3&V4,'Upper Lower Database'!A:P,MATCH(U11,'Upper Lower Database'!1:1,0),FALSE),)") //Flight
    shUserForm.getRange("V14").setFormula("=IFERROR(V13/V12,0)") //Desired eng rate
    shUserForm.getRange("V15").setFormula("=IFERROR(V5/V13,0)") //Desired eng rate
    shUserForm.getRange("V20").setFormula("=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($V$3,'2023 Summary'!$C:$AQ,MATCH($U20,'2023 Summary'!$C$5:$AQ$5,0),false),)") //CSM
    shUserForm.getRange("V21").setFormula("=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($V$3,'2023 Summary'!$C:$AQ,MATCH($U21,'2023 Summary'!$C$5:$AQ$5,0),false),)") //RVP
    shUserForm.getRange("V22").setFormula("=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($V20,Vlookups!$I:$J,2,false),)") //CSM Slack ID
    shUserForm.getRange("V23").setFormula("=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($V21,Vlookups!$I:$J,2,false),)") //RVP Slack ID
    shUserForm.getRange("V24").clear().setBackground('#FFFF00');//upper and lower


  }
}
```